# Photo organization software?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management

I take alot of photos, on windows I have used [picasa](http://picasa.google.com/linux/) - and sure, it is a wine-based version available for linux. What alternatives are available on Ubuntu that can at least handle RAW Support, Organization, Editing and Uploading to the web?

*Please include one piece of software per answer including an overview of features and a description of the software*

Comment: This question really isn't [in a great format](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask). Asking for the "Best" is subjective and will change from person to person. I've changed your question to avoid having it closed and to make it more objective. In this new format it's now a Poll which isn't much better and is barely considered an acceptable type question.

Comment: Abhijeet, Picasa "for Linux" is just Picasa for Windows bundled with Wine. That's what Thomas was referring to in the question.

Answer (score 4):

[**Shotwell**](http://yorba.org/shotwell/) , (Default in Ubuntu): [Install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shotwell).

> 1. Import photos from folders or from any digital camera supported by [gPhoto](http://gphoto.org/).
> 2. Shotwell automatically groups photos taken at the same time. You can also use tags and ratings to organize your photo collection.
> 3. You can rotate, crop, reduce red-eye, and adjust the exposure, saturation, tint, and temperature of each photo.
> 4. Publish photos and videos to Facebook, Flickr, Picasa Web Albums, and YouTube.
> 5. Basic support for RAW images, including import support for all common formats like CR2 and DNG.

**Screenshot**
[image]